# Group by as a list and create new colum for each value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where every row is a user id and if he has an item:

```
| user | item_id |
|------|---------|
|  1   |   a     |
|  1   |   b     |
|  2   |   b     |
|  3   |   c     |
|  4   |   a     |
|  4   |   c     |
```

I want to create n columns where n is all the possible values of item_id, group one row per user and fill 1/0 according if the value is present for the user.

```
| user | item_a  |  item_b |  item_c  |
|------|---------|---------|----------|
|  1   |   1     |     1   |     0    |
|  2   |   0     |     0   |     0    |
|  3   |   0     |     1   |     1    |
|  4   |   1     |     0   |     1    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.crosstab(df.user,df.item_id).add_prefix('item_').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1,1,2,3,4,4], 'item_id': list('abbcac')}) 
df = df.assign(val=1).pivot_table(values='val',
                                  index='user',
                                  columns='item_id',
                                  fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to use get_dummies and group by sum where:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['item_id']).groupby('user').sum().reset_index()
```

desired result:

```
    user    item_id_a   item_id_b   item_id_c
0    1         1          1          0
1    2         0          1          0
2    3         0          0          1
3    4         1          0          1
```

and to change the columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"_id", "")
```

df

```
       user item_a  item_b  item_c
0         1     1    1       0
1         2     0    1       0
2         3     0    0       1
3         4     1    0       1
```